# Upper bound on $ \binom{a}{m+1}\sum ^m_{j=0} \binom{a-m-1}{j}/\binom{b}{j+m+1}$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Given $a,b,m$ such that $0<2m<a<b$.
I would like to find out upper bound of $$S = \binom{a}{m+1}\sum ^m_{j=0} \frac{\binom{a-m-1}{j}}{\binom{b}{j+m+1}}$$
Anyone can help me please?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Maybe this can help:
$$
\frac{a!}{(a-m-1)!(m+1)!}\cdot\sum_{j=0}^{m}{\frac{\left(\frac{(a-m-1)!}{(a-m-j-1)!j!}\right)}{\left(\frac{b!}{(b-m-j-1)!(j+m+1)!}\right)}}
\\= \frac{(b-a)!a!}{\,b!}\sum_{j=0}^{m}{\frac{(b-m-j-1)!}{(a-m-j-1)!(b-a)!}\frac{(j+m+1)!}{(m+1)!j!}}
\\=\binom{b}{a}^{-1}\sum_{j=0}^{m}{\binom{b-m-j-1}{b-a}\binom{j+m+1}{m+1}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

It is crude but you may proceed as follow. For every $0 \leq j \leq m$ we have
$$\frac{\binom{a-m-1}{j}}{\binom{b}{j+m+1}} \leq \binom{a-m-1}{j} \leq (a-m-1)!$$
and so 
$$ \begin{array}{rcl}S&=&\binom{a}{m+1}\sum ^m_{j=0} \frac{\binom{a-m-1}{j}}{\binom{b}{j+m+1}} \\ &\leq & \binom{a}{m+1} (m+1)(a-m-1)!\\ &=& \frac{a!(m+1)(a-m-1)!}{(m+1)!(a-m-1)!}\\ &=& \frac{a!}{m!}\end{array}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I begin by using this identity: $\int_0^1 t^{\alpha} (1-t)^{\beta}=\frac{!}{\alpha+\beta+1}\frac{1}{\binom{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha}}$, for some positive $\alpha$ and $\beta$. This can be alternatively expressed as follows: for some positive $n$ and $k$, we have $\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}= (n+1) \int_0^1 t^{k}(1-t)^{n-k} dt$. Applying this to the right hand side, we have:

$$S=(b+1) \binom{a}{m+1} \sum_{j=0}^m \binom{a-m-1}{j} \int_0^1 t^{j+m+1}(1-t)^{b-j-m-1} dt\\
=  (b+1) \binom{a}{m+1} \int_0^1 (1-t)^{b-m-1} t^{m+1} \left[\sum_{j=0}^m \binom{a-m-1}{j} \left( \frac{t}{1-t}\right)^j \right] dt \\
\leq (b+1) \binom{a}{m+1} \int_0^1 (1-t)^{b-m-1} t^{m+1} \left[\sum_{j=0}^{a-m-1} \binom{a-m-1}{j} \left( \frac{t}{1-t}\right)^j \right] dt
\\
= (b+1) \binom{a}{m+1} \int_0^1 (1-t)^{b-m-1} t^{m+1}  \left[ \left(1+ \frac{t}{1-t}\right)^{a-m-1} \right] dt
\\
= (b+1) \binom{a}{m+1} \int_0^1  t^{m+1} (1-t)^{b-a} \\ 
=  \frac{b+1}{b-a+m+2}    \frac{ \binom{a}{m+1}}{\binom{b-a+m+1}{m+1}}
\\
=(b+1)\frac{a!(b-a)!}{(b-a+m+2)!(a-m-1)!}
$$

In case I have made arithmetic mistakes, I am sure you can pick it up and mend it, since I hope the main logistics are clear

Comment: Thanks. But it seems complicated expression. Could you simplify it?

Comment: I am afraid that this is as simple as it gets. Let me also add that, a quick numerical check verifies that this bound is far tighter than $\frac{a!}{m!}$.

Comment: Also note that in the case of $a=2m+1$, the bound equals the sum.

Comment: thanks.your upper bound is >1?

Comment: Not necessarily. The sum itself can be smaller than or greater than unity, depending on the parameters. For example, for $\{m,a,b\}=\{2,5,9\}$, you get $S= 0.357=bound$, below unity. Conversely,  for  $\{m,a,b\}=\{2,7,9\}$, you get $S=3.194$ and $bound=5.83$, both above unity.

Comment: thanks. I'm trying to check if $a<b/2$ or $a<b/3$ then the bound $<=1$ or not? any suggestion for this?

Comment: @Fotouhi: I've just asked other similar problem. Could you please consider it? Thanks.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882055/upper-bound-s-n-sum-n-mk-left-binomb-an-m-sum-m-j-0-righ